# how to assert a value from another file in gatling

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

Im new to gatling tool trying to assert an value from the response and the same response value is been saved in another file now to assert the value.

.check(jsonPath("$.id").is(TestParameters.locationId))

TestParameters is the file where I had saved the value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way to deliver variables is a [Feeder](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/session/feeder/).

Storing variables in a file isn't a very nice solution. You can use ordinary variables for this purpose. Nevertheless, if you so want to use the file, then you just need to write a function that will read from the file and write to the feeder.